# Cannot sort a linked list of dynamically assigned nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

My program takes in any number of words from the user, and stops only when the user types three asterisks (***). These words will be stored in a linked list and sorted, but the elements in the list are not sorted when I try to print the list. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 32  // Limit on length of each string


/* Link list node */
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

// Function to insert a given node in a sorted linked list
void sortedInsert(struct Node**, struct Node*);

// function to sort a singly linked list using insertion sort
void insertionSort(struct Node **head_ref)
{
    // Initialize sorted linked list
    struct Node *sorted = NULL;

    // Traverse the given linked list and insert every
    // node to sorted
    struct Node *current = *head_ref;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        // Store next for next iteration
        struct Node *next = current->next;

        // insert current in sorted linked list
        sortedInsert(&sorted, current);

        // Update current
        current = next;
    }

    // Update head_ref to point to sorted linked list
    *head_ref = sorted;
}

/* function to insert a new_node in a list. Note that this
  function expects a pointer to head_ref as this can modify the
  head of the input linked list (similar to push())*/
void sortedInsert(struct Node** head_ref, struct Node* new_node)
{
    struct Node* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->data >= new_node->data)
    {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *head_ref;
        while (current->next!=NULL &&
                current->next->data < new_node->data)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}

/* BELOW FUNCTIONS ARE JUST UTILITY TO TEST sortedInsert */

/* Function to print linked list */
void printList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

/* A utility function to insert a node at the beginning of linked list */
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    /* put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}


// Main function
int main()
{
    struct Node *a = NULL;

    int index=1;
    int i;
    char * strings[MAX_STRINGS]; // Array of pointers

    do
    {

        strings[index] = malloc(MAX_STRING_LEN * sizeof(char));
        printf("Please input a word : ", index);
        fgets(strings[index],MAX_STRING_LEN,stdin);

        strtok(strings[index], "\n")=='\0';

    }
    while(strcmp(strings[index++], "***")!=0);

    printf("\nThe input set, in alphabetical order:\n");

    for (i = 1; i < index-1; i++)
    {
    push(&a, strings[i]);    
    }

    insertionSort(&a);
    printList(a);
    free(strings[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
pear
apple
***
```

Given output:

```
 pear
 apple
```

Expected output:

```
apple
pear
```

Comment: `int index=1;` You store starting from index 1 yet you print from index 0.

Comment: Okay I've changed i=0 to i=1 in the for loop. But my linked list still isn't being sorted :(

Comment: Doesn't your compliler give warnings? `push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)` that and the node struct stores `int` as data. But `push(&a, strings[i]);`. You are passing in a `char *`. I'm not sure what you are intending. Why does the node not store the string? Why store an `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hii I spent some time thinking what you wanted to do. And saw many problems with your code. I think you want something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 32  // Limit on length of each string
#define MAX_STRINGS 100 // Limit the number of strings

struct Node {
    char *data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void sortedInsert(struct Node **head_ref, struct Node* new_node) {
    struct Node *counter = *head_ref;
    struct Node *previous = NULL;
    while (counter != NULL && strcmp(counter->data,new_node->data) < 0){
        previous = counter;
        counter = counter->next;
    }
    if (previous != NULL) {
        previous->next = new_node;
        new_node->next = counter;
    } else {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
}

void push(struct Node **head_ref, char *new_data) {
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (!head_ref) {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;        
    }
    sortedInsert(head_ref,new_node);
}

void printList(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void freeLinkedList(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *next;
    while(head) {
        next = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(next);
    }
}
// Main function
int main() {
    struct Node *a = NULL;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    char * strings[MAX_STRINGS]; // Array of pointers
    do {
        strings[index] = malloc(MAX_STRING_LEN * sizeof(char));
        printf("Please input a word %d: ", index);
        scanf("%s",strings[index]);
        fflush(stdin);
    } while(strcmp(strings[index++], "***") != 0 && index < MAX_STRINGS);
    printf("\nThe input set, in alphabetical order:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < index-1; i++) push(&a, strings[i]);
    printList(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested it and it works fine.
If you have any doubts I would like to clear them.
If you want to know what's buggy in your code please feel free to ask.

Comment: Hii Jim Hecker , If my answer is the one you were looking for please updoot and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Can you explain how the new sortedInsert and push function work? I've selected this as the answer

Comment: Basic principle of insertion sort is "Inserting a new value in already sorted list". Here this begins with a single element and inserts new elements into it's right place. sortedInsert is checking the linked list (by comparing string in new_node with counters and inserting it between previous and counter. if there is no previous the new_node becomes the head. 
Thanks for asking :)